# Compiled funtion don't understand internal compiled function

Tags: compile

I work a lot on Mathematica and sometimes I need to optimize my computations by using compiled functions. Now I'm making numerical integrations and I'm trying to compile the functions involved to make everything faster. I'm having basically the fallowing issue which explain by it self:

`gCC = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, x^2];`

`fCC = Compile[{{R, _Real}},
   NIntegrate[gCC[x + y]*Boole[x^2 + y^2 < R^2], {x, -R, R}, {y, -R, R}]
   ];`

Then when I use the function `fCC` I get the fallowing error:

`fCC[2.1]`

`CompiledFunction::cfsa: Argument x+y at position 1 should be a machine-size real number. >>`

`30.549`

How can I solve this? Regards.

Comment: [`NIntegrate[]` is not compilable.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1101)

Comment: Have a look at documentation regarding the (optional) third argument of `Compile`. It might be useful in this situation. Also the `Compile` options for inlining might apply.

Comment: Just to take one level off the problem, if you try `NIntegrate[
 gCC[x + y]*Boole[x^2 + y^2 < 2.1^2], {x, -2.1, 2.1}, {y, -2.1, 2.1}]` it gives the same error, so the issue is not with the definition of `fCC`

Comment: Try this:  `gCC = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, x^2];
gCC2[x_?NumericQ] := gCC[x];
fCC = Compile[{{R, _Real}}, 
   NIntegrate[
    gCC2[x + y]*Boole[x^2 + y^2 < R^2], {x, -R, R}, {y, -R, R}]];
fCC[2.1]`

Comment: Thanks JasonB, your simple solution worked and now my computations are considerably faster ! Sorry for my delayed feedback.